# Lxml object not found in lxml tree during search after adding in it in tree

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, lxml

> Content inside Test.arxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AUTOSAR xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0 AUTOSAR_4-2-1.xsd">
<AR-PACKAGES>
<AR-PACKAGE>
  <SHORT-NAME>AUTOSAR</SHORT-NAME>
</AR-PACKAGE>
<AR-PACKAGE>
  <SHORT-NAME>BALL</SHORT-NAME>
</AR-PACKAGE>
```

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml import objectify
from lxml.etree import fromstring

tree = objectify.parse('Test.arxml')
root = tree.getroot()
namespaces = {}
namespaces['ar'] =  root.nsmap[None]

xpath = './/ar:AR-PACKAGE/ar:SHORT-NAME'
hits = root.xpath(xpath, namespaces=namespaces)
```

Status of [hits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXUz7.png)

```
new_element_string = "<AR-PACKAGE xmlns:None='http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0'><SHORT-NAME xmlns:None='http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0'></SHORT-NAME>{0}</AR-PACKAGE>".format("AUTOSAR_Platform")
new_element_node = node = objectify.fromstring(new_element_string)

root['AR-PACKAGES'].append(new_element_node)
second_hits = root.xpath(xpath, namespaces=namespaces)
```

Status of [second_hits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1y7t.png)

> Question:
> Why 'AUTOSAR_Platform' is not seen as third package inside second_hits ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your text in the wrong place in the node you're appending. You probably want

```
new_element_string = "<AR-PACKAGE xmlns:None='http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0'><SHORT-NAME xmlns:None='http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0'></SHORT-NAME>{0}</AR-PACKAGE>".format("AUTOSAR_Platform")
```

to be

```
new_element_string = "<AR-PACKAGE xmlns:None='http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0'><SHORT-NAME xmlns:None='http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0'>{0}</SHORT-NAME></AR-PACKAGE>".format("AUTOSAR_Platform")
```

And then to get the namespaces to match:

```
new_element_string = "<AR-PACKAGE xmlns='http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0'><SHORT-NAME>{0}</SHORT-NAME></AR-PACKAGE>".format("AUTOSAR_Platform")
```